# A/C Repair Honda Pilot

Tags: honda, ac, pilot

I have a Honda Pilot and the AC wasn’t working. Brought it in and they recharged it.   A few weeks later, it wasn’t working again so they replaced the condenser.  Two weeks later, it’s not working again. They replace a gasket or o ring (no charge this time). And just now, it stopped putting out cold air againand they replaced an o-ring.  This is the fourth time I’ve gone in for the same thing (A/C)

Should they have replaced the o-rings when they replaced the compressor?  I feel I’m being taken advantage of but am not sure. Is this a possible normal occurance.  Please advice.  In the past i felt like this shop was taking care of me and trying to be resourceful. But I wonder if I just am getting shoddy serviced or a lower price

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I'd be trying a different garage (maybe a dealer, even if only for a correct diagnosis). These people seem to just be throwing parts at a problem in the hope that the parts solve the problem *this time*. You need a competent garage who can diagnose the actual problem, and then fix it in one go.

Comment: You can actually search for leaks yourself.Buy a Wood's lamp, go in a dark place, turn it on and scan the engine bay with it.Point it at the compressor,examine it thoroughly and then follow the piping from the compressor and examine any part (including the condenser and any fitting).If you can reach the evaporator from inside the car, point it at the evaporator's fins too. Most car makes and AC techs add the UV dye to the oil when charging the AC system up with refrigerant and oil. You can actually do that without the blacklight if you have good eyesight: just look for any oily patch anywhere.

Comment: Each shop has its competencies and its weak spots. They might be as honest as the day is long, but just in over their head on this problem. As PeteCon suggests, they are down to throwing parts at the problem, so time to find another shop, at least for this issue.